# what did I do on my linux box, used the rm incorrectly

Tags: unix

What will this command do on unix:

```
rm somefile ~/data
```

I was trying to move somefile to the folder at home/data

Comment: You deleted the file.

Comment: I don't think it will appear any useful answers out of this awful question.

Answer (score 3):

It will delete `./somefile` and, if it's a file, `~/data` (assuming you have permission to do so on both of them, of course).

The command you *wanted* was:

```
mv somefile ~/data
```

If you don't do regular backups, you're probably hosed.

Answer (score 2):

`rm` means `remove`...

You wanted `mv`, which means `move`

### `rm somefile ~/data`

That command deletes `somefile`, and also deletes `~/data` (`data` file located in the home directory).

If you wanted to rename/move (the two are the same) `somefile` to `~/data`, the proper command would of been:

```
mv somefile ~/data
```

Comment: Yes, when I do cd ~ I don't see the /data folder anymore!  But I do see if it I go to /home/xxxx/users folder.  Was it just mirrored or aliased then?  How can I get it back?

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to use `mv`:

```
mv somefile ~/data
```

`rm` means remove.

Answer (score 0):

You removed somefile completely.

rm means 'remove'.

You need 'mv'

Use 'man rm' and 'man mv' for more information.

Answer (score 0):

rm is the remove command.
see [man rm](http://swoolley.org/man.cgi/rm)

Answer (score 0):

Bash/Ubuntu:

```
meder@meder-desktop:~$ rm lol ~/lmfao
rm: cannot remove `/home/meder/lmfao': Is a directory
```

As previously stated you want 'mv'