# I did rm instead of mv, how can I reference my data folder again?

Tags: unix

In this question: [what did I do on my linux box, used the rm incorrectly](https://superuser.com/questions/14080/what-did-i-do-on-my-linux-box-used-the-rm-incorrectly/14086#14086)

I basically did a rm instead of a mv.

Anyhow, it turns out the /data folder I deleted which was in my home folder is still present somewhere else in my shell i.e. /home/my_user_id/data

So I guess the one I deleted was just a reference/alias to that folder??

How can I re-create this alias so when I do: cd ~  and then ls I see the /data and /domains folder again. (domains is there as I didn't delete that!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't quite follow your explanation, but you may be after the `ln` command.

Basically, if you have a folder `/stuff/data`, and you want that to be available to you as `~/data` without moving it, you can do:

```
ln -s /stuff/data ~/data
```

This will create a symbolic link `~/data` pointing to `/stuff/data`.  If you then do a `ls -l` you will see something like:

```
[other columns omitted]  data@ -> /stuff/data
```

Comment: bingo!  The other folder in my .home was also a symbolic link.  Thanks for clearing this up!